# How to identify the different prefab items in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I have defined a prefab with name is "Item" and contain in Resources
Then, I load that prefab in GUI (Unity3D)

```
  Object prefab_item = Resources.Load("Item");
  GameObject g = Instantiate(prefab_item) as GameObject;
  g.transform.parent = this.transform; 
  g.transform.position = pos;
  Sprite sprite = Resources.Load("Images/item_" + item, typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
  g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;
```

I want to load a list of different items by "Item" prefab, 
How to identify the different items when pressing them?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give each game object you created a name:

```
int i=1;
g.name = string.Format("item {0}", i);
```

Then you can identify it using:

```
var object = GameObject.Find("item 1");
```

In case you want to handle it when it is pressed, you can:

1. add a collider component to the game object;
2. add OnMouseDown() function in that MonoBehaviour script
3. attach the MonoBehaviour script to the game object programatically:

   g.AddComponent("YourOnMouseDownScript");

Comment: How to get name GameObject and then compare it? When i pressing any one of them? Thanks David!

Comment: g.name returns the name of the game object and you can use string.Contains(...) function for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
Debug.Log ("item name: " + gameObject.name);
```

You can write this:

```
Debug.Log ("item name: " + gameObject.name, gameObject);
```

Then the message will be clickable in the log window. The object will be selected when you click the log message.

Comment: It only show log the first item 1, not show items 2, 3, ...9.
Although, i press to item 2, 3, ...9
May be, because i define a prefab, and then i load this prefab?

Comment: Yeah, then you should think how are these items being created? If your prefab is item 1 and you instantiate it several times, you will have lots of clones of "item 1", not any "item 2". If you manually rename the objects, then they can be "item 2", "item 3"...

Comment: Thank you David and piojo! I have completed :)